# Is the json import failing because of the JSON file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a simple python program that should load a .json file into a variable and print the variable output to the screen. But it fails to run and errors with the following message:

```
"File "/Documents/VSCode/python-3-programming-specialization/Data Collection and Processing with Python (Course 3)/Lesson 1/assessment6.py", line 5, in <module>
    res = json.load(json_file,)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 15 column 25 (char 506)"
```

In the JSON file there is an error too that I think is the problem but I don't know what values to set to clear the error in the JSON file. The error occurs anywhere you see a None, True or False value.

JSON error message: "Value expected json(516)

```
    "statuses": [
      {
        "contributors": None,
        "truncated": False,
        "text": "RT @mikeweber25: I'm decommiting from the university of Michigan thank you Michigan for the love and support I'll remake my decision at the\u2026",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": None,
        "id": 536624519285583872,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
        "retweeted": False,
        "coordinates": None,
```

```py
import json

with open('./tweets.json') as json_file:
    res = json.load(json_file)

print(res)
```

The expected output should be the file read in by the python program.

Comment: Looks like the json file does not contain valid json (at least what you posted isn't valid).

Comment: `None`, `False` - these don't exist in JSON, that's Python; it should be `null` and `false`. It looks like whoever wrote that out didn't actually do it as JSON, so either use `ast.literal_eval` or actually make it JSON.

Comment: The JSON I posted is only a snippet, I didn't post the entire file. The error happens at those None and False lines.

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe. I'll make the changes and see what happens.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, changing None to null and False to false, resolved the problem. Thanks!